# How do I display images from a JSON file in a carousel(slider) in Flutter

Tags: json, dart, flutter, carousel

I have a local json file `assets/properties.json` in which key "image" has [5 different images] stored with other keys as well like name, place, etc. I want this images be displayed in a carouselSlider.

I have searched but cant find something specific to what i am trying to do.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test_app/test_page.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_test_app/propery_details_widget.dart';

class PropertyDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PropertyDetailsState createState() => _PropertyDetailsState();
}

class _PropertyDetailsState extends State<PropertyDetails> {
  List properties;
  Future<String> loadJsonData() async {
    var jsonText = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/properties.json");
    setState(() {
      properties = json.decode(jsonText);
    });
    return 'success';
  }
  int index = 1;

  List<String> listaTela = new List();

  CarouselSlider instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.loadJsonData();

    listaTela.add("assets/images/houses/house.jpg");
    listaTela.add('assets/images/houses/house1.jpg');
    listaTela.add('assets/images/houses/house2.jpg');
    listaTela.add('assets/images/houses/house3.jpg');
    listaTela.add('assets/images/houses/house4.jpg');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    instance = new CarouselSlider(
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlayDuration: new Duration(seconds: 2),
      items: listaTela.map((it) {
        return new Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
//          margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(

//            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
          child: new Image.asset(it),
        );
      }).toList(),
      height: 200,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Test App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            instance,
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Container(
                child: Details(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of calling images from assests `listaTela.add("assets/images/houses/house.jpg");` like this i want to call them from my "image" key in JSON file. outside my Carousel i can call my images by `properties[index]["image"][0],`

Comment: Instead of calling images from assests ```listaTela.add("assets/images/houses/house.jpg");``` like this i want to call them from my "image" key in JSON file. outside my Carousel i can call my images by ```properties[index]["image"][0],```

Comment: What's in the JSON file? How is the image stored there? In base64? Can you give an example of what your JSON looks like?

Comment: @RichardHeap ```{
    "image": ["assets/images/houses/house.jpg", "assets/images/houses/house1.jpg","assets/images/houses/house2.jpg", "assets/images/houses/house3.jpg", "assets/images/houses/house3.jpg"
    "town": "Rehoboth",
    "location": "236 Block D"
    "status": "For Sale"
    "price": "N$ 1 250 000.00"
}``` , so i want to display the images direct from here instead of calling them from assests... thank for having a look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. (There's a chance that the `map` won't work because it will have the wrong type. I don't think you included the whole json, as you are indexing it by `index`, yet you don't show a `[]` surrounding the json indicating a json array.)

```
class _PropertyDetailsState extends State<PropertyDetails> {
  List properties;
  int index = 1;

  Future<void> loadJsonData() async {
    var jsonText = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/properties.json");
    setState(() {
      properties = json.decode(jsonText);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadJsonData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget carousel = properties == null
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : CarouselSlider(
            items: properties[index]["image"].map((it) {
              return new Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(),
                child: new Image.asset(it),
              );
            }).toList(),
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayDuration: new Duration(seconds: 2),
            height: 200,
          );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Test App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            carousel,
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Container(
                child: Details(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @RichardHeap you are a ```rockStar```... It gave an error but just needed to add ```<Widget>``` to map like this ```items: properties[index]["image"].map<Widget>((it)``` and it worked. Thanks again much appreciated..!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you problem, there are a couple of challenges.

1. you probably want to map the JSON to Dart objects
2. you want to display a set of images in the Slider starting from index
3. mechanics to update you widget tree when you want to update the slider

**JSON and Dart**

Takes some getting used to built `package:built_value` is a nice way to go. It will allow you to have Dart object or list of objects mapped from a JSON file. Or, if you want to go simpler, you could do what's described here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-manually-using-dartconvert

**Images from index & update**

Basically, what you want to do in your `initState` is:

```
load image data from json -> set start index -> somehow get Flutter to map N image paths to Image widgets and update tree
```

A pseudo-code like `initState` could look like so:

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // step 1: load json and map it to Dart objects
  this.loadFromJson().then(() {
    // loadFromJson returns with a Future, `then` allows you to do computation after it returns
    setState(() {
      // setting property in setState tells Flutter: hey buddy, stuff happened, rebuild!
      this.startIndex = 0;
    });
  });
}
```

inside your build:

```
// [...]
CarouselSlider(
  items: listaTela.skip(this.startIndex).take(5).map((imgObj) => Image.asset(imgObj.assetPath))
);
```

Hope I understood your problem and gave you relevant answer.

Comment: thanks for you reply but when trying to add ```// step 1: load json and map it to Dart objects
  this.loadFromJson().then(() {
    // loadFromJson returns with a Future, `then` allows you to do computation after it returns
    setState(() {
      // setting property in setState tells Flutter: hey buddy, stuff happened, rebuild!
      this.startIndex = 0;
    });
  });``` everything is undelined red?

Comment: That doesn't help me much to help you fix it. The editors have an "analyzer" tab that tells you why it's underlined red. Please, examine those errors. I'm betting that you can fix some of those errors quickly.