# How to Display Currency Format with Separators in EMI Calculator in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, decimal, currency

I build a EMI calculator in flutter, but my results display as e.g `1250568.00` but wan it to display as `N$ 1,250,568.00`

i have tries the intl package but get a error on `Text(f.format(_tiResults)),` as explained how to implement it. also tried the MoneyMask package to no avail.

```
import 'package:homenet/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List _durationTypes = ['Month(s)', 'Year(s)'];
  String _durationType = "Year(s)";
  String _miResult = "";
  String _tiResult = "";
  String _tcResult = "";
  bool _switchValue = true;

  final TextEditingController _principalAmount = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _interestRate = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _loanDuration = TextEditingController();

  _onClear(){
    setState(() {
      _principalAmount.text = "";
      _interestRate.text = "";
      _loanDuration.text = "";
      _miResult = "";
      _tiResult = "";
      _tcResult = "";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFFA983A),
        title: InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new HomePage()));},
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/logo_white.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel, size: 30,),
            onPressed: () {
              _onClear();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                  controller: _principalAmount,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  gapPadding: 5),
                  labelText: "Enter Principal Amount"),

                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                  controller: _interestRate,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                              gapPadding: 5),
                          labelText: "Interest Rate per Annum %"),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Container(
                      child: TextField(
                        cursorColor: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                        controller: _loanDuration,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                gapPadding: 5),
                            labelText: "Loan Duration"),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
//                  TODO: ========= SWITCH ================
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          _durationType,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Switch(
                            activeColor: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                            value: _switchValue,
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              print(value);

                              if (value) {
                                _durationType = _durationTypes[1];
                              } else {
                                _durationType = _durationTypes[0];
                              }

                              setState(() {
                                _switchValue = value;
                              });
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
//              TODO: ============== Button ============
              Flexible(
                child: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(48, 8, 48, 8),
                  onPressed: _handleCalculation,
                  child: Text(
                    "CALCULATE",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
//              TODO: Results Widget =====================================
              monthlyInstalmentsResult(_miResult),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              totalInterestResult(_tiResult),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              totalCostResult(_tcResult),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  "Disclaimer* This is just an approximate amount"
                  "and in no way reflect the exact figures, please consult your bank.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 10,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleCalculation() {
//    TODO: Amortization
    //    TODO: A = Payment amount per period
    //    TODO: P = Initial Principal (Loan Amount)
    //    TODO: r = interest Rate
    //    TODO: n = Total number of payments

    double A = 0.0;
    double I = 0.0;
    double T = 0.0;
    double P = double.parse(_principalAmount.text);
    double r = double.parse(_interestRate.text) / 12 / 100;
    int n = _durationType == "Year(s)"
        ? int.parse(_loanDuration.text) * 12
        : int.parse(_loanDuration.text);

    A = (P * r * pow((1 + r), n) / (pow((1 + r), n) - 1));
    T = (A * n);
    I = (T - P);

    _miResult = A.toStringAsFixed(2);
    setState(() {});
    _tiResult = I.toStringAsFixed(2);
    setState(() {});
    _tcResult = T.toStringAsFixed(2);
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget monthlyInstalmentsResult(miResults) {

//    var f = new NumberFormat("#,###,###.0#");
//    var f = new NumberFormat("###.0#", "en_US");
    bool canShow = false;
    String _miResults = miResults;

    if (_miResults.length > 0) {
      canShow = true;
    }
    return Container(

        child: canShow
            ? Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Monthly Instalments: ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "N\$ ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    _miResult,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            : Row());
  }

  Widget totalInterestResult(tiResults) {
    bool canShow = false;
    String _miResults = tiResults;

    if (_miResults.length > 0) {
      canShow = true;
    }
    return Container(
        child: canShow
            ? Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Total Interest: ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "N\$ ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    _tiResult,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            : Row());
  }

  Widget totalCostResult(tcResults) {
    bool canShow = false;
    String _miResults = tcResults;

    if (_miResults.length > 0) {
      canShow = true;
    }
    return Container(
        child: canShow
            ? Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Total Cost: ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "N\$ ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    _tcResult,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            : Row());
  }
}
```

The code is reproducable exactly as i have it inmy app.... I want the results (`miResults` ,`tiResults` and `tcResults`) display in financial/currency format. thank you.

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproduction of your code? It would be easier for us to replicate and find a solution for you.

Comment: The code posted above is fully reproducible. A rare thing to see here on SO.

Comment: What's not working? This seems to do it. `NumberFormat format = NumberFormat('#,###,###.00');
  print('N\$${format.format(1250568.00)}');`

Comment: It is @HugoPassos ...

Comment: Yes @MazinIbrahim i find it easier this way than to have to post code multiple times...

Comment: @RichardHeap I did but gives an errot ```Class 'String' has no instance getter 'isNegative'.``` when i do this ```('N\$${format.format(_ _miResult)}')```

Comment: @GriffinFisch I truly apperciate your way of composing questions, it makes answering them easier than other questions with trimmed code. My response was actually directed to the first comment. And by the way keep this style, and you'll always find a quick and good answer to your questions.

Comment: @MazinIbrahim No problem... I an still new to this so i have to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @GriffinFisch You can't use a number formatter on a string - you need to use it on a number - see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  void _handleCalculation() {
    //    TODO: Amortization
    //    TODO: A = Payment amount per period
    //    TODO: P = Initial Principal (Loan Amount)
    //    TODO: r = interest Rate
    //    TODO: n = Total number of payments

    double A = 0.0;
    double I = 0.0;
    double T = 0.0;
    double P = double.parse(_principalAmount.text);
    double r = double.parse(_interestRate.text) / 12 / 100;
    int n = _durationType == "Year(s)"
        ? int.parse(_loanDuration.text) * 12
        : int.parse(_loanDuration.text);

    A = (P * r * pow((1 + r), n) / (pow((1 + r), n) - 1));
    T = (A * n);
    I = (T - P);

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat('#,###,###.00');
    setState(() {
      _miResult = format.format(A);
      _tiResult = format.format(I);
      _tcResult = format.format(T);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am still getting this error ```Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'isNegative'.``` if i put it in setState ir says "A" "I" and "T" isnt defined?

Comment: A, I and T are defined, just a few lines above... `double A = 0.0;
    double I = 0.0;
    double T = 0.0;` - can you update the question showing the new version that says A isn't defined?

Comment: finally got it right after moving it around a thousand times. Thank you finally got it going by putting your code at the botton of my  ```_handleCalculation()``` code. thank you... much apreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Don't forget to accept the answer if useful.

Comment: do you perhaps have any insights on this if you don't mind? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221889/how-do-i-display-images-from-a-json-file-in-a-carouselslider-in-flutter